# Is it safe to close the client during a network render while it is rendering?

Tags: rendering, network

I have 3 PCs in my network: my main that I can't bog down with rendering so I made it the client; my laptop which I've made the master because it's not great at rendering; and my old PC which I've made the slave.

My question is that while the master is managing the render job can I close the client program on my main computer and then reconnect to the master later to get all the files it has rendered so far?

Currently I'm using it to render the frames using the cycles engine for an animation I made.

Edit: I'm using the 2.79 version of blender for windows.

Answer (score 2):

I found that you can close the client once you send the render job to the master. The master is what needs to keep running.